# Django Rest Framework Related Query?

Tags: django

There is 3 models, Article(post) Follow(To follow a user) User, How can I get all the post of user I'm following?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=400)
    body = RichTextUploadingField()


class Follow(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                  related_name='rel_from_set',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                related_name='rel_to_set',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   db_index=True)


class User(models.Model):
    pass
```

Comment: You need the Post from all the users you are following right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get all the Post from all the users followed by the request.user:

```
Article.objects.filter(author_id__in=self.request.user.rel_from_set.all().values_list('user_to_id'), flat=True)
```